# Building a ReactJS & React Native Hybrid App

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a project where I will need to create a shared code environment for React and react native.

I know that for the most part, you cannot share the presentational components between the two but I would love to share some of the core logic as well as the app structure in a singular codebase.

Of course, due to the way React and React Native are packaged, there are some catches, some of which are solutions I mentioned.

The idea is to use logic similar to this blog post:
http://jkaufman.io/react-web-native-codesharing/

For the sake of not having to worry about creating the whole build process, I created a starter package that uses the cli for `create-react-app` and `react-native` (from the `react-native-cli`).
https://github.com/ReyHaynes/react-redux-web-native

Obviously, there will be some issues using this method, but if you guys let me know of some showstopper issues with this process? I'd love to hear them!

Also, if you have time to try the hybrid build and see issues with it, I'd love to hear that as well.